# DBContext error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext

I'm using entity framework (Database first) and when I run my program I get this error:

> The context is being used in Code First mode with code that was
>   generated from an EDMX file for either Database First or Model First
>   development.  This will not work correctly. To fix this problem do not
>   remove the line of code that throws this exception. If you wish to use
>   Database First or Model First, then make sure that the Entity
>   Framework connection string is included in the app.config or
>   web.config of the start-up project. If you are creating your own
>   DbConnection, then make sure that it is an EntityConnection and not
>   some other type of DbConnection, and that you pass it to one of the
>   base DbContext constructors that take a DbConnection. To learn more
>   about Code First, Database First, and Model First see the Entity
>   Framework documentation here:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=394715

My connection string is:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="PayRollContext"
     connectionString="Data Source=ATI_SHAH\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=PayRollManagmentSystem;Integrated Security=True;"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

I searched for this error but I do not understand it.

Comment: What don't you understand? The connection string you show is not an EDMX connection string.

Comment: Fix your connection string... Remove it from the config and update your EDMX. It will show a popup where you can regenerate the connection string.

Comment: what is fix in connection string , programming is really disgusting same thing run one day but not another , i think its not suitable for me im leaving . . .

Comment: Well yeah if you can't handle a setback now and then and sometimes a little frustration, programming probably isn't for you. Don't let that demotivate you. Though you did something to make it not work, you did not explain what. It's hard for us to help here. See my updated previous comment though, this should regenerate the proper connection string in your configuration.

Comment: Best response ever! Seriously though, software development is often a lot of blood, sweat and tears, but the payoff when you have a completed product is worth it....

Comment: but I'm not able to do this :) @DavidG

Answer (score 0):

Do you have multiple contexts? If you share a connection across two or more contexts this will not work. However if you use a different connection for both it will work.

Answer (score 0):

The connection string you have is not for database first workflow. It's actually used for code first workflow. Normally for database first, you don't actually have to modify the connection string yourself (all done via designer).

Here is the correct format of connection string used in database first workflow:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="PayRollContext"
       connectionString="metadata=res://*/model.csdl|res://*/model.ssdl|res://*/model.msl;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=ATI_SHAH\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=PayRollManagmentSystem;Integrated Security=True;&quot;"
       providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I assume your `edmx` file is `model.edmx`

I think you should follow the wizard importing model from database again to understand how it works.